# Clarification on Apple App Store Guidelines - Use of WebUIView

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm new to mobile programming. Recently my company has looked into creating a specific application for tablets (Android and iOS). So it was assigned to me to develop a thin-client based around using HTML5 for what we need to do.

Essentially the application allows a user to fill in a custom-designed form (which the user can build themselves, or pull down a predefined template from our server). This form is built using HTML5, Javascript, JQuery, etc. Some additional functionality is planned, such as being able to take a picture using the native device and attach it to the form that we send back to our server for storage (once we figure out how to do it in iOS. We've already done it in Android.)

However, I noticed the following on Apple's App Store Guidelines, under the [Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality) section. Item 2.12:

*Apps that are not very useful, unique, **are simply web sites bundled as Apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected*

Can someone explain, or at least direct me to clarification of this when using the UIWebView construct? This application at its core is pretty much just HTML5. While it might have some additional bells and whistles, does this mean that if we try to submit this (when its completed) to Apple, that they will simply reject it out of hand? Implementing the majority of it in HTML5 was done purposely so we wouldn't have to re-code everything from device to device (and we will also embed it in one of our products, so if they want to fill it out on the desktop while in our system, they can.)

Any guidance would be appreciated, or even suggestions of where this question should be asked if SO is not the proper forum for it. Thanks again.

Comment: You can create your mobile app(ios/android) using cross-platform technology using phone gap and query mobile read this link (1) http://phonegap.com/ (2)http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/ (3)http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in the Appstore guideline is the word "simply":

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as
>   Apps

If you keep a balance between locally stored and remote HTML content for your webviews Apple would not look at the app as a hollow shell pulling in remote content.